# Windows Phone 7.1 Development - User Login Pattern

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, authentication, windows-mobile, silverlight-5.0

Many thanks in advance to anyone who can spare their time and effort in helping me with this matter.

I am currently developing a Windows Phone Application (targetting Mango).  I am very new to this type of Development.  As part of this application, I need to implement a user login pattern very similar to this:

http://windowsphonepatterns.net/uap_pattern/login

The general process being that a user enters their credentials (typical login screen), they press submit/login, their credentials are then authenticated against an xml webservice - whilst the application shows a new screen with an inderterminate progress indicator until the web service either comes back (authenticated yes/no) or times out.  Pretty run of the mill stuff (or so I thought).

Thus far, I have developed a login screen and code that consumes an xml webservice.  The part where I am struggling is linking a new page, with an indeterminate performanceprogress indicator on it, to the activity of consuming a web service (using silverlight WebClient).  Functionality like the login of the Last.FM app.

I have searched online to try and find good examples of how to do this, but haven'y any luck so far.

Does anyone have/know of any code that could demonstrate how to do this.  Some code that implments the above pattern would be an awesome help.

Again, many thanks in advance.

Chris

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be keep both the login controls and progress indicator on the same page but on two different canvas.
So initially when the page loads hide the canvas containing progress indicator and only show the login controls.
When the user enters the credentials and taps approve button hide the login controls by simply hiding its canvas and showing the progress indicator canvas.
And in the callback method of your xml webservice you can navigate the new page  if credentials are correct.

Comment: And, consider using visual state manager to show/hide those canvas. I usually have 3 visual states on my login pages: normal, pending (=progress indicator visible), and failed (=error message visible).